# Посчитать количество контейнеров с суммами

Tags: java, алгоритм, list

Имеется список чисел:

```
List<Float> weight
```

Нужно посчитать, на сколько различных комбинаций суммой до 10.0 можно разбить эти числа. Комбинации с переставленными слагаемыми являются одной и той же комбинацией.

Например, `[ 1.1, 2.2, 9.9 ]` выдаст ответ `2`, т.к. возможно 2 комбинации суммой до 10 включительно: `9,9` и `1.1 + 2.2 = 2.3`.

---

Сделал код:

```
public static int efficientJanitor(List<Float> weight) {
    Collections.sort(weight, Collections.reverseOrder());
    int count = 1;

    for (int i = weight.size() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        if (weight.get(i) + weight.get(i - 1) <= 3.0) {
            weight.set(i - 1, weight.get(i) + weight.get(i - 1));                    
        } else {
            count++;       
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

На малых количествах считает всё верно, однако при запуске более крупных тест-кейсов начал выдавать ошибки.

Что может быть не так? Предел для суммы я установил 3.0.

Comment: Не нужно публиковать как ответ. Вы можете внести [правки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1006705/edit) в свой вопрос (:

Comment: не самый оптимальный вариант использовать здесь сортировку, поскольку ты вначале забьешь "контейнеры" маленькими значениями и что делать дальше с большими - уже вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Эту задачу можно решить с помошью [Динамического программирования](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Пример кода (правда это больше расчитанно на int значения)

```
public int combinationSum(List<Float> weights, int target) {
    int[] dp = new int[target + 1];

    dp[0] = 1;
    for (int j = 1; j <= target; j++) {
        for (float weight : weights) {
            int k = j - (int) weight;
            if (k >= 0) {
                dp[j] += dp[k];
            }
        }
    }
    return dp[target];
}
```

Comment: не совсем понятно, для чего в вашем коде служит переменная 'target`

Comment: @Ep1demic это и будет 'суммой до 10.0'  из условия